# Share specific value from a Service with different component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I am new in Angular and have a problem. I am trying to pass some data between components. I already tried different solutions found on the internet and I am not getting it right.

I get data with two values (headline and id) via an service from an api in one component (this works fine). While clicking on the headline, I want to be redirected to an another component and receive the id of the clicked headline in order to call another api endpoint. How do I call the specific value id and bring it into the other component?

This is my first service (working):

```
export class HeadlinesService {
   apiUrl = '...'

   httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
   };

   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

   getHeadlines(): Observable<Headline[]> {     
     return this._http.get<Headline[]>(this.apiUrl); 
   }

}
```

My headline class:

```
export class Headline {
   heading: string;
   id: string;
   source: string;
}
```

Here I call the Service in order to display the headlines (working)

```
export class NewArticleComponent implements OnInit {

    headlines$: Headline[];

    constructor(private headlineService: HeadlinesService, private deleteService: DeleteService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       return this.headlineService.getHeadlines()         
       .subscribe(headline => this.headlines$ = headline)
    }
}
```

I need a service which receives the id from the service above (but only id) and calls another api endpoint with it.

```
apiURL = '.../{id}'
```

The calling of the data from this should work like the working service above, so my only problem is to pass the id from one serve to another.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Clicking the `Headline` will redirect the user to another section (Angular page or state) with resources specific to the clicked `Headline`, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data on navigation with this:

```js
constructor(...
  router: Router,
  ...) {}

goToPage(headerId) {
  this.router.navigate(['/header'], { queryParams: { headerId } });
}
```

Assuming you are doing it programatically (from inside your component.ts code)

And on the "receiving" headers component

```js
sub: Subscription;
headerId;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .pipe(flatMap(params => {
        this.headerId = params['headerId'];
        return this.apiService.getById(this.headerId);
      })).subscribe(
        response => {
          //You should have your header response from API here
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you :). Now I want to use it to get data from another api. I tried to get with a similar get method like above, but giving the id as an parameter: this in my component.ts: `code` return this.dataService.getData(this.headerID)      .subscribe(data => this.data$ = data) and this in my service: `code`getData(headerID): Observable<Data[]> { return this._http.get<Data[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/${headerID}`); } but it wont work. Do you know how to solve it correctly?

Comment: Check the update I made for your requirement. The ```flatMap``` operator is introduced because having nested subscriptions is an antipattern.

https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/fixing-rxjs-anti-patterns